# HttpClient ReadAsAsync<IQueryable<T>> never returns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

Im quite new to writing controllers for asp.net and Im trying to return IQueryable, but I cant seem to get the call for the content to return.

This is my controller:

```
    // GET: api/RumsaRooms
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<RumsaRoom> GetRooms()
    {
        return db.Rooms;

    }
```

and this is my client call:

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAllOf<T>()
    {
        var typeName = typeof(T).Name;



        var result = await _client.GetAsync($"api/{typeName}");

        if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var exception = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


        }
        //This method never returns
        var rooms = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IQueryable<T>>(); 

        return rooms;



    }
```

I have enabled multipleactiveresultsets in the connectionstring. 
The StatusCode is 200.

The method that GetAllOf() looks like this:

```
    private async Task<bool> LoadEntities()
    {
        var rooms = (await _rumsaClient.GetAllOf<RumsaRoom>()).ToList();

        RoomsCollection = new ObservableCollection<RumsaRoom>(rooms);


        return true;
    }
```

LoadAllEntities is called in the constructor of my viewmodel.
If I change the call to this it works:

`var rooms = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<T>>();`

Is it not possible to ReadAsAsync to a IQueryable?

Thanks

Erik

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost certainly in this code:

> LoadAllEntities is called in the constructor of my viewmodel.

I explain [why this deadlock happens](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in detail on my blog. It doesn't have anything to do with `ReadAsAsync` or `IQueryable`. It has to do with calling `Wait` or `Result` on an asynchronous task.

In summary:

- Tasks returned by `async` methods are only completed when that method completes.
- `await` by default captures a "context" and uses that "context" to resume the `async` method.
- On ASP.NET, this "context" is an instance of `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, which only allows one thread in at a time.
- When the code calls `Wait`/`Result`, it will block the thread (which is still in the ASP.NET request context), waiting for the task to complete.
- When the `await` is ready to resume the method, it does so in the captured context, and waits for the context to be free.
- Since `await` cannot complete the method until the context is free, and the context is in use by a thread waiting until the method completes, you end up with a deadlock.

The proper way to solve this is to not block on asynchronous code; use `await` instead. This principle is called "[async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)", and is described in my MSDN article on async best practices. Since you're trying to call asynchronous code from a constructor, you may also find my blog post on [async constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) helpful, which explains some alternative approaches.